# How can change url with apache settings?

Tags: apache

I want this link:

```
http://example.com/wiki/index.php?title=Page_title
```

became this link:

```
http://example.com/wiki/Page_title
```

but I dont know how?
and where should I put htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/wiki/(.+)  /wiki/index.php?title=$1  [R,L]
```

this should go in to your site root htaccess

Read this [Redirecting and Remapping with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html)

Comment: can you show me a reference that help me to understand what you wrote?

Comment: The [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directive takes two [regular expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/glossary.html#regex) and rewrites any URL matching the first one to the second one. It appears that Anuradha got it backwards though - the regexes should be switched.

Comment: for this to work you need to enable the mod_rewrite extension on your server.